# How to draw the trajectory of a moving particle

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I want to draw a 3D graph showing a nanoparticle movements in liquid environment. Basically,the code is like the followings. I used Table to generate the position coordinates instead of using the random movement position for simplicity here. My problem is I want to make the trajectory shown as connected lines instead of discrete points while maintain a rainbow-like color.

```
pts = Table[{t/100, (t/100)^1, (t/100)^2}, {t, 1, 100}];
pts1 = Table[{{t1/100, t1/100}, (t/100)^2}, {t1, 1, 100}, {t2, 1,100}];
Graphics3D[{Thickness[0.05], Hue[#], Point[#]} & /@ pts, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps [`VertexColors`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/VertexColors.html) achieves what you're after?

```
Graphics3D[{Thickness[0.005], Line[#, VertexColors -> Hue /@ #]} &@ pts, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you want a "purer" rainbow, perhaps use just the first coordinate of the `pts`:

```
Graphics3D[{Thickness[0.005], Line[#, VertexColors -> Hue /@ #[[All, 1]]]} &@ pts, 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In this case, the coordinates happen to go from `0` to `1`.  If not, you could use [`Rescale`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Rescale.html):

```
VertexColors -> Hue /@ Rescale[#[[All, 1]]]
```

Comment: That's perfect. Thanks

Comment: @MYG  You're welcome.